# Design View Structure

Tags: android-studio

I upgraded my Android Studio and then look has changed. I can no longer see the "Phone View".

This is what I see

[image]

And this is what I was seeing (Notice the Blue Bar or the phone interface on the left)

[image]

I searched google for Android Studio Design Structures and other terms. I also wen through their tutorails but I coudn't figure it out. been at it for couple of hours now. Hope I am not missing something very simple?

Comment: There's that dropdown with the eye, select Show Layout Decorations and see how it goes.

Comment: Damn! Thanks.... It helped :D you may want to put that as an answer? Could you also help me out, how to change the "icon" and the name of the app which shows on the phone. I can't find the options for those as well

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to change the name and icon for the app then open the AndroidManifest file and change the icon and label properties to what you like.

Comment: Yes I saw that, `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, `android:label="@string/app_name"` But ealrier I could do that using a visual editor?

Comment: I can go to  `res folder -> values -> strings.xml` and manually edit it but I want the old designer back :D

Comment: strings.xml does have an editor, but it's more for helping with translation https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor?utm_source=android-studio

Comment: Let research on how to get that designer back... Anyways.. thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UI you have a dropdown with an eye icon for some viewing options. In that dropdown you should enable Show Layout Decorations.